# list: overfull error

Tags: line-breaking, warnings

I'm getting error:

> `Overfull \hbox (11.66551pt too wide) in paragraph`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url} % typeset URL's reasonably
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pslatex} % Use Postscript fonts
\usepackage[numbers, square]{natbib}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
\usepackage{pst-plot} % For axes

\usepackage{float}

\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Global Analysis Method: External resources such as dictionaries and thesaurus(e.g. WordNet) are used to add terms to the query before the search process 
\item Local Analysis Method: Information from retrieved resources is used to formulate the new query. Thus, the success of this method is is highly dependent on the precision of the first search
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE with the `\documentclass`?

Comment: ...and please tell us what your problem is!

Comment: That means that one line (you didn't say which) of your input does not fit into the text width (but you didn't say what that was) at the current font size (which you haven't told us) and the current font (which we don't know). People need to be given at least some clues if you want them to help.

Comment: @m0nhawk, I modified the question

Comment: @SvendMortensen, the problem is that i'm getting the error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, its the line with the first item

Comment: @Noor You should provide a minimal working example (see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @SvendMortensen, I've given the preamble, the place where the error is occurring and the error itself, so I can give more info, just please tell me what i'm missing, I'm not a latex expert, so I may not know what's important

Comment: All you have to do is read the meta post I linked to and you should know what a minimal working example is.

Comment: @SvendMortensen, ok modified

Comment: Add a space after "thesaurus": `thesaurus (e.g. WordNet)`.

Comment: it works, whats the error, because I'm getting this issue several places??

Comment: It's not an error it's a warning that TeX could not find a good place to break the line. In that case there was a missing space in your source (and word spaces are a good place to break) in other cases the reasons will be different. You can ignore it or fix each case (or you could try adding `\sloppy` which tells latex to lower its standards and use less good line breaking)

Comment: If you add the `draft` option to the documentclass (`\documentclass[draft]{article}`) you will get a black box on the lines causing the warning, which can be a helpful visual aid.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you make your comment here an answer?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an error, it's a warning that TeX could not find a good place to break the line.

In that case there was a missing space in your source (and word spaces are a good place to break) in other cases the reasons will be different. You can ignore it or fix each case (or you could try adding `\sloppy` which tells latex to lower its standards and use less good line breaking.